# Excel: Highlight text in cell not the cell (without vba)

Tags: excel

How can i highlight specific text in excel not complete text ?
(without using vba)
I tried conditional formatting but that highlight complete cell instead of specific text in cell.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without vba. However, I made a variable vba that you can run just like CTRL+F... it counts and highlights instances of your search term... see my answer to this question on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/1130183/is-there-any-easy-way-to-search-for-a-specific-word-within-a-cell/1130500#1130500

Comment: worked very well... thanks

Comment: i saved this as "Excel Add-In" (.xlam) and then in "excel>option>Add-Ins>manage"      i added this....

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following range (A1 to A4)

**Username**
Jatin
John Doe
Mary Williams

**You can do it the following way**:

1. Conditional Formatting
2. Manage Rules
3. New Rule
4. Use formula to determine which cells to format
5. Format values where this formula is true:

On the above step, input the following formula (change it to whatever range or formula you wish to)

***=$A2="Jatin"***

6. Format
7. Font tab
8. Select the formatting you want to apply
9. Change the range it applies to (=$A$2:$A$4)

[image]

Comment: Can you post what type of data are you trying to highlight?

Comment: for example: cell contain text "jatin" then, that only text should be highlighted or bold..... instead of complete cell.

Comment: thanks for the help..... but it is working on complete cell where cell have only that specific text.... but i want it to highlight in cell... check this.... used vba but working very well.......    http://superuser.com/questions/1130183/is-there-any-easy-way-to-search-for-a-specific-word-within-a-cell/1130500#1130500

Comment: From what i saw from the link you provided, you want to highlight the text background only. From what i searched, you cannot do that with the default formatting (non VBA) options Excel provides you, sorry. I think you really have to get into VBA to achieve that.

Answer (score -2):

Edit the cell value, select the word you want to highlight, highlight it.